# How to define 'phi' so I don't get an error for trying to multiply a non-int by a complex number in the exponential

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix

Using:

```
arr2 = np.array([np.arange(0,20)]*20,dtype=np.complex_)

for a in range(arr2.shape[0]):
 for b in range(arr2.shape[1]):
    if a-b:
        arr2[a,b] =1-(1j/np.sqrt(3))
    else:
        arr2[a,b] = np.e**(1j*phi*abs(a-b))
```

to produce a matrix of size N * N which I have defined as a * b above gives the error 'TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex''.

I need to define \phi however I do not want python to solve it numerically.
I want my output to be of the form (this is just an example of the first 3 terms of the first 3 lines of the matrix where i is an imaginary number):

```
( 1-(i/sqrt(3)) ,    e^(i{\phi})    ,    e^(2i{\phi})  ,  ... )
( e^(i{\phi})   ,  1-(i/sqrt(3))    ,    e^(i{\phi})   ,  ... )
( e^(2i{\phi})  ,    e^(i{\phi})    ,  1-(i/sqrt(3))   ,  ... )
(     ...       ,       ...         ,      ...         ,  ... )
```

instead of trying to numerically solve this matrix, is there a way to express the matrix in the general form I have displayed above? Would a simple

```
arr2inv = inv(np.matrix(arr2))
```

return the inverse of the general form I want or produce an error?

So to summarise:

1. How do I define phi to remove the complex-non-int error?
2. How do I get python to produce the general form shown above?
3. Will it invert without an error?

Comment: Numpy evaluates everything numerically. For symbolic computation have a look at [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/intro.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest and faster way to do that numerically is :

```
i=np.arange(20)
phi = (1 + np.sqrt(5))/2                       # for example  :) 
a_b = np.abs(np.subtract.outer(i,i))           # make all the differences in a matrix
arr2 = np.exp(1j*phi*a_b)                      # compute the exp
np.fill_diagonal(arr2, 1-1j/np.sqrt(3))        # set the diag
```

For symbolic approach python have the `sympy` module which can manage that ; 
 it will probably difficultly simplify `inv(arr2)` with `rank = 20`. but numpy is good to quickly check a mathematical assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and related can only handle numerical computations. If you need an output for the matrix as you describe consider using Mathematica or another equivalent symbolic manipulation software.